# How to gain weight naturally or by food around the house

Tags: nutrition, diet, micronutrients, weight, vegetarianism

I'm 24 years old, vegetarian and weigh 31Kg. Can anybody tell me how to increase weight naturally and what food to keep around the house?

Also I would like to ask, in my childhood I did not take breast milk, can that affect my body growth and contribute to the development of illnesses in the future?

Comment: House provisional? Do you mean food around the house? And do you mean veterinarian (Doctor who cares for animals) or vegetarian (Non meat eating)?

Comment: Not trying to scare you but I once saw a girl online who was really thin and that was because of some problem with her _adipose tissue_ which is responsible for metabolizing the fats. No matter, how much she eats, she couldn't gain weight. I would strongly suggest you to consult a general physician. Hope for the best.

Comment: This has been answered thoroughly over on PF-SE: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle there are some ideas about what to eat here: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/weight-gaining-diet-for-vegetarian

Comment: Yes, Breast milk is the best food of the universe and you should have taken it at least for 2 years. Yes, that causes consequences for a long time. May I ask why you did not take breast milk?

Comment: Also, by being vegetarian you have a less protein intake. However, there are other ways of protein intake. You should eat eggs, boiled eggs, when the water starts to boil, you put it in, count 7 minutes, take it out. Eat at least 6 a day. Eggs are the second best food in the planet, there is nothing proved about something wrong with eggs. Font: [Dr. Lair Ribeiro who worked at Harvard Medical School, Baylor College of Medicine and Thomas Jefferson University](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM35RRVNPEE)

Comment: SEE a doctor. [31kg is way too low regardless of body size](https://www.bcbst.com/mpmanual/HW.htm). This is a potential deadly health issue (in fact, 31kg seems really really low to me), so you need to see a professional as soon as possible.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you are very short, your weight indicates that you are severely underweight, [see here for details](http://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/). If you are indeed underweight, then you should follow the advice given there:

> If you are concerned about being underweight, please seek a trained healthcare provider.

The general advice that comes second to whatever your doctor's advice is, is given on [this page on healthy weight gain](http://www.eatright.org/resource/health/weight-loss/your-health-and-your-weight/healthy-weight-gain). So, you'll need to increase your calorie intake, but make sure you get enough nutrients from all food groups.

Answer (score 5):

To increase weight and be healthy eat plenty of food rich in proteins (black beans, chickpeas, broccoli, potatoes, mushrooms), carbohydrates (Whole grain bread, pasta, cereals) and fat (avocado, olive oil, almonds, walnuts); include supplements and multivitamins in your diet, lift weights (don't do running or cardio) and plan your diet according to your activity level.

http://www.gainingweight101.com/gaining-weight-vegetarian-bodybuilding-diet-without-meat/

http://www.peta.org/living/food/top-10-vegan-protein-sources/

http://www.veggienumnum.com/nutrition/carbohydrates-dietary-fibre/

http://www.helpguide.org/articles/healthy-eating/choosing-healthy-fats.htm

http://www.veganhealth.org/articles/fatstable

Answer (score -2):

These are the most important steps and tips that help you gain weight for those who do not suffer from diseases and health problems:

1. Eat three main meals during the day, plus two or three snacks between meals, preferably drinking milk or fresh juices with meals or between them to increase calories in the body.

2 - refrain from drinking water before eating and reduce drinking between meals so as not to lose appetite.

3 - Limit the intake of foods containing unsaturated fats, because they raise the level of insulin in the blood.

4 - Avoid eating vegetables and fruits that contain amounts of water, such as watermelon, orange and squash.

5. You should gradually gain weight, as 500 calories a day increase your weight by five kilograms a week.
6. Take enough rest every day and sleep for enough hours.
7. Exercise to speed up metabolism, this makes your body needs more calories and therefore needs to eat larger amounts.

http://www.pickshape.com/how-to-gain-weight-fast/

http://www.pickshape.com/how-to-gain-weight/

Comment: There's no way that eating an additional 500 calories per day will increase body weight by 5 kilograms per week. Not even close.

Answer (score -3):

The cardinal rule here is to ensure that you consume more calories than you burn ***on a daily basis***.

You will wish to establish a long-term healthy eating pattern.  But in the short-term, I would suggest without hesitation that whatever you choose to eat - place it between two slices of bread and add plenty of cheese.

Comment: This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)

Comment: To be honest I was just chipping in with common knowledge.  I will consider sources.